# C# - Working alternative to delegate type in interfaces

Tags: c#, types, interface, delegates

I'm working on an huge existing code and i need to adapt it to other environment
This comes from a DLL:

```
public interface IGH_DocumentObject : IGH_InstanceDescription
{
    public delegate void PingDocumentEventHandler(IGH_DocumentObject sender, GH_PingDocumentEventArgs e);
    event PingDocumentEventHandler PingDocument;
}
```

and here's an example of how it's referred from other methods:

```
private void UnregisterObjectEvents(IGH_DocumentObject obj)
{
    obj.PingDocument -= new IGH_DocumentObject.PingDocumentEventHandler(this.DocObjectPingDocument);
}
```

I can't change every reference to this code, so i've to find a way to make this second code to work using the interface above

Comment: `obj.PingDocument -= this.DocObjectPingDocument;` should work fine in `UnregesterObjectEvents`. My compiler doesn't like it when interfaces declare types, so I can't get far enough with your code to see what the actual problem is. What problem are you having? Is there an error message?

Comment: the error is the same as yours (probably):
"Interface cannot declare types"
I know that i can't put delegated method inside an interface,
But i can't declare them outside the interface or i can't refer to them like "IGH_DocumentObject.PingDocumentEventHandler()"

Comment: You can't just declare the delegate type outside of the interface?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't, I've to edit this part inside a much bigger project that call this instruction several times, I can't change all the references to this code, so I've to find a way to make this syntax work:
`obj.PingDocument -= new IGH_DocumentObject.PingDocumentEventHandler(this.DocObjectPingDocument);`

Comment: If I take this delegate outside the interface, in the same CS script can I then reference this delegate inside the interface so that the IGH_DocumentObject.PingDocumentEventHandler may refer to something?

Comment: See my first comment above. Try it that way. But if somebody is telling you to compile code that cannot be compiled, tell them to go argue with Microsoft. That's an insane requirement. It's impossible. They are requiring you to flap your arms and fly. That cannot be done.

Comment: I tryied that way but it's not working, i'm editing a decompiled DLL that works just fine, but there are several method written in the wrong way, for example a lot of methods with get and set are referred like `get_Method()` instead of `Method`... This is just another example of a part of the code that is impossible to compile also if it comes from a decompiled DLL, the way you suggested doesn't work, it's the obvious solution that everyone use, I know, but I can't use it 'cause every other call to this Type won't work that way

Comment: It looks like the DLL was written in Visual Basic .NET, which allows interfaces to declare types. I need **three** things from you: Please share the *exact* code which "didn't work" when you tried what I suggested. Copy and paste it into your question. Also, I need to see the code for your event handler method `this.DocObjectPi‌ngDocument`, and tell me the EXACT error message that you got. The full and exact complete error message.

Comment: Ok, i rewrote part of the code and changed every reference to this delegate type, I can't get stuck in this point, this was the only way, i simply created an abstract class between this interface and the classes that implements it, implementing the abstract class, changing a little the structure of the project, it seems to work now

Comment: if you had provided me the information I asked for, I could've shown you the solution. I got an identical delegate definition working in five minutes for myself. But if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

OP refuses under any circumstances to show me the version of his code without the delegate constructor, or to tell me what error message the compiler gives him on it. He ended up inventing some kind of workaround.

However, there's an explanation for what he's seeing, and a very easy fix.

In C#, it's forbidden to define a delegate type (or any type) in an interface. In VB.NET, it's permitted. So the assembly they're decompiling must have been written in VB.NET (or potentially some other .NET language that allows the same thing, but VB is the natural candidate -- does C++/CLI allow it?).

So the C# compiler sees this, and it's obviously illegal code:

```
obj.PingDocument -= new IGH_DocumentObject.PingDocumentEventHandler(this.DocObjectPingDocument);
```

The obvious solution is this:

```
obj.PingDocument -= this.DocObjectPingDocument;
```

You don't ever need a delegate constructor if the handler has the correct prototype. So that works if `this.DocObjectPingDocument` has the correct prototype, because the C# compiler isn't forced to come to terms with the embarrassing fact that its little brother VB.NET compiler has a feature it doesn't.

But OP claims it doesn't work. He refuses to show me the code in which he tried it. So it's possible he didn't try it, or that he didn't do what I told him -- but another likely explanation is that the event handler has the wrong prototype.

The following event handler can be added and removed without the delegate constructor. I duplicated the interface definitions in a VB.NET assembly, referenced that from a C# assembly, and tested it. This compiles and OP's version with the constructor doesn't compile, for the reasons he gave.

```
protected void DocObjectPingDocument(IGH_DocumentObject sender, 
    GH_PingDocumentEventArgs e) 
{
}
```

These cannot be added and removed (in C#, at least) without a delegate constructor:

```
protected void DocObjectPingDocument(IGH_DocumentObject sender, 
    EventArgs e) 
{
}

protected void DocObjectPingDocument(object sender, 
    GH_PingDocumentEventArgs e) 
{
}
```

It's worth including this answer because that feature of VB.NET could cause somebody else the same problem.